# Как в Nuxt регистрировать роуты или куда пропала папка server?

Tags: nuxt.js

Ранее при создании Nuxt проекта через SLI появлялась папка с названием server в ней был файл index.js благодаря которому можно было регистрировать роуты. На скриншоте изображено как это было раньше. Теперь папка server при создании проекта отсутствует. Как теперь используется данная функциональность?
[image: index.js]

[image: app.js с регистрацией роутов]

Comment: Документацию читать - не, сразу делать на авось - лучший вариант!)))

Comment: Кинь ссылку где, об этом почитать можно.

Answer (score 2):

Сейчас роуты в nuxt генерируются автоматически согласно структуре файлов в директории pages
https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing

Прочие настройки роутинга можно указать в файле nuxt.config.js в параметре router
https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router

Comment: Я про роуты контролеров, там же видно на скриншоте.